# What function $f(x)$ gives the maximal $\frac{\int_0^1 \log f(x)\,dx}{\left(\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \min(x,y) f(x) f(y)\,dx\,dy\right)^{\!1/3}}$

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

> What function $f(x)$ gives the maximal of 
>   $$\frac{\int_0^1 \log f(x)\,dx}{\left(\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \min(x,y) f(x) f(y)\,dx\,dy\right)^{\!1/3}}?$$

I've found $f(x) = \sqrt{e}/x$ gives a high value, and I wonder if there's a nice method finding the actual optimum or giving an upper bound. Not just in this case, but for general functionals.

Comment: What does $\min(x,y)f(x)f(y)$ mean in the integrand of the denominator? Does it mean that you're really calculating $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\left[\min(x,y)f(x)f(y)\right]dx\,dy? $$

Comment: Note that \begin{align*}\int_0^1\int_0^1\min(x,y)f(x)f(y)\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^1\left[\int_0^y xf(x)f(y)\,dx+\int_y^1 yf(x)f(y)\,dx\right]dy\\ &=\int_0^1\left[f(y)\int_0^y xf(x)\,dx+yf(y)\int_y^1 f(x)\,dx\right]dy.\end{align*}

Comment: yes, it means we're integrating $[\min(x, y) f(x) f(y)]$

Comment: Alternatively the functional has min where this functional has min:

$L(f) = \frac{\int_0^1 \log f(x)\,dx}{\left(\int_0^1 \int_x^1 x f(x) f(y)\,dx\,dy\right)^{\!1/3}}$

Since they only differ in a constant.